# Is there an efficient way to calculate something like a heatmap on a node graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, heatmap

I'm programming a simple game simulation where I have some computer controlled creatures that move on a nodegraph. They want to go towards targets (think, say, wolves wanting to go towards rabbits).

I've already implemented simple pathfinding so a creature can find the fastest route directly towards a given target node, but in the case of multiple targets (lots of food on multiple nodes), I think I want to generate something like a heatmap gradient on the graph so the wolves can just query neighbor nodes and go towards the hottest neighbor.

Anybody know of an efficient way to generate a heatmap on a graph? The fastest way I can think of is to do N full graph traversals (N=number of food nodes), each time doing a BFS (or, closest/hottest-unvisited-node-first-traversal) starting at each food node, calculating heat from that food-node on each node in the graph, and then summing all the heat from each food in one collection pass. I don't like this because, well, if I have a large graph and a large number of food nodes, I may have to do many full graph traversals, each with many nodes.

I was thinking of doing a kind of BFS where I start with an open set of all the food nodes and move outwards from there, but then I'd be calculating the distance to the closest food node only; a cluster of food nodes would not generate a very hot location because I can't go back to increase heat in a previously traversed node (and if I do allow that, I'm essentially visiting every node N times like my previous example anyway). e.g. if I start with:

```
F-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-O
| | | | | | | | |
F-O-O-O-O-O-O-O-F
```

where F is food and O is an empty node, and say a food node has a heat of 5 and there's a decay of 1 per node, what I WANT my heatmap to look like is

```
9-7-5-3-1-1-2-3-4
| | | | | | | | |
9-7-5-3-2-2-3-4-5
```

but a BFS style traversal (where any node can only be visited once) will look like:

```
5-4-3-2-1-1-2-3-4
| | | | | | | | |
5-4-3-2-2-2-3-4-5
```

Anybody got a cleverer way to do this?  Worst case maybe I can do my multiple N-times graph traversal, but on a schedules, so I do only one food-node traversal every X seconds...

Answer (score 3):

Why not simulate the flow of heat around the graph? That is, if temperature of node *i* at time *t* is T<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*), then set:

> T<sub>*i*</sub> (*t* + 1) = α F<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*) + (1 − β) T<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*) + γ Σ<sub>*j* ∈ n(*i*)</sub> T<sub>*j*</sub> (*t*)

where F<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*) is the amount of food on node *i* at time *t*, n(*i*) is the set of neighbours of node *i*, and α, β and γ are parameters of the simulation. α is the rate at which heat enters the system, β is the rate at which heat exits the system, and γ is the rate at which heat flow from a node to its neighbours. All of these should be small numbers: you will have to find good values for them by experimenting.

Using this equation, it takes O(|nodes| + |edges|) to update the temperature of every node, so you should be able to compute it regularly (ideally every frame).

The equation above is for a discrete simulation (with constant time step). If you have variable time step δt, then try:

> T<sub>*i*</sub> (*t* + δt) = δt α F<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*) + (1 − β)<sup>δt</sup> T<sub>*i*</sub> (*t*) + δt γ Σ<sub>*j* ∈ n(*i*)</sub> T<sub>*j*</sub> (*t*)

Comment: Wow, that is very helpful and really easy to implement. Thanks! I'll give it a shot. I already have variable timestep so I may as well implement that. Also, I can then update it on a schedule if it's too resource intensive per frame...

Comment: Hi, I am finally getting around to implementing this (darn day job). I was wondering if you knew what I should substitute for γ if I have edges of different lengths. That is, if γ=f(L), where L is the length of the edge, what is f(x)? My simulation doesn't have to be anywhere near "correct", but I'd like it to satisfy the property where, if I ran enough steps, 2 nodes 10 units apart would and a line of 3 units 5 units apart would converge on roughly the same heat transfer between the two end nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Your general approach is good, but I think you are being blinded by your heatmap concept. In essence you want to compute a weighted average location of all targets, and have your hunters head for that point. I would implement this as follows:

1. If any target closer than N, then track the closest target; else
2. Compute weighted average location of all targets closer than Max, with weighting function = D^2 (just a guess, but quick to calculate because no square root required). Hunters head for that location on each iteration.
3. Repeat from 1.